# How to draw nodes of graphs connected by curve lines?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-cd

How to make nodes of graphs connected by curve lines that looks like:

[image]

My working:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,matrix,positioning,shapes,arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, arrows, calc, intersections}
\newcommand{\tikznode}[2]{\relax
    \ifmmode%
    \tikz[remember picture,baseline=(#1.base),inner sep=0pt] \node (#1) {$#2$};
    \else
    \tikz[remember picture,baseline=(#1.base),inner sep=0pt] \node (#1) {#2};%
    \fi}

\begin{document}    
    \begin{figure}[!h]
        \centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}
        \centering
        \coordinate (a) at (0,0);
        \coordinate (b) at (0,-2);
        \coordinate (c) at (2,-1);
        \coordinate (d) at (4,-1);
        \coordinate (e) at (7,-1);
        \coordinate (f) at (9,-1);

        \draw (a) node[left]{$v_0$};
        \draw (b) node[left]{$v_3$};
        \draw (c) node[above]{$v_1$};
        \draw (d) node[above]{$v_2$};
        \draw (e) node[above]{$v_0$};
        \draw (f) node[above]{$v_1$};

        \draw [fill=black] (a) circle (2pt);
        \draw [fill=black] (b) circle (2pt);
        \draw [fill=black] (c) circle (2pt);
        \draw [fill=black] (d) circle (2pt);
        \draw [fill=black] (e) circle (2pt);
        \draw [fill=black] (f) circle (2pt);
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

which produces

[image]

Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is rather simple with some `to[in=..,out=..]` paths.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{quotes}
\begin{document}    
    \begin{figure}[!h]
        \centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}[dot/.style={inner sep=2pt,fill,circle},auto]
        \path[nodes=dot]  (0,0) node[label=left:$v_0$] (a) {}
            (0,-2) node[label=left:$v_3$] (b) {}
            (2,-1) node[label=above:$v_1$] (c) {}
            (4,-1) node[label=above:$v_2$] (d){}
            (7,-1) node[label=above left:$v_0$] (e){}
            (9,-1) node[label=above right:$v_1$] (f){};
            \draw (a) to[out=0,in=135,"$e_1$"](c) 
            to[out=-45,in=-135,"$e_2$"'] (d)
            to[out=45,in=90,"$e_3$"]++(1.5,0)
            to[out=-90,in=-45] (d)
            to[out=135,in=45,"$e_4$"'] (c)
            to[out=-135,in=0,"$e_5$"] (b);
            \draw (e) to["$e_1$"] (f)
            (e) to[out=90,in=90,"$e_3$"] (f)
            to[out=-90,in=00] ++ (-0.5,-1.5) 
            to[out=180,in=00] ++ (-1.5,0)node[below left]{$e_4$} 
            to[out=180,in=180] (e);
            \draw[white,line width=4pt,postaction={draw,black,thin}]
                (f)     to[out=0,in=90] ++ (1,-0.25) node[right,black]{$e_2$}
            to[out=-90,in=-90] (e);
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

A general answer: did you try \usepackage{tkz-berge}? With the AlterMundus manual you should be able to get it done nicely.